# How do I understand this figure about antenna pattern?

Tags: antenna-theory

[image]

Why the back lobes have such a large area??? I think it may be like https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/wireless/aironet-antennas-accessories/prod_white_paper0900aecd806a1a3e.doc/_jcr_content/renditions/0900aecd806a1a3e_null_null_null_08_07_07-03.jpg 
this image on the right side figure. That may look normal.

Here's the data from pattern file excel:**2 0 0 360** 0 -13.31 1 -13.21 2 -12.93 3 -12.46 4 -11.85 5 -11.17 6 -10.50 7 -9.86 8 -9.28 9 -8.75 10 -8.24 11 -7.75 12 -7.26 13 -6.78 14 -6.32 15 -5.90 16 -5.53 17 -5.23 18 -4.99 19 -4.80 20 -4.67 21 -4.57 22 -4.52 23 -4.51 24 -4.53 25 -4.61 26 -4.73 27 -4.90 28 -5.08 29 -5.25 30 -5.34 31 -5.30 32 -5.10 33 -4.78 34 -4.36 35 -3.92 36 -3.50 37 -3.13 38 -2.84 39 -2.61 40 -2.44 41 -2.32 42 -2.24 43 -2.19 44 -2.17 45 -2.17 46 -2.22 47 -2.30 48 -2.43 49 -2.60 50 -2.80 51 -3.04 52 -3.29 53 -3.56 54 -3.85 55 -4.12 56 -4.32 57 -4.36 58 -4.12 59 -3.52 60 -2.58 61 -1.42 62 -0.18 63 1.06 64 2.21 65 3.27 66 4.22 67 5.09 68 5.87 69 6.60 70 7.29 71 7.94 72 8.59 73 9.22 74 9.84 75 10.43 76 11.01 77 11.55 78 12.04 79 12.50 80 12.90 81 13.26 82 13.58 83 13.85 84 14.10 85 14.32 86 14.52 87 14.71 88 14.87 89 15.02 90 15.14 91 15.23 92 15.28 93 15.29 94 15.26 95 15.17 96 15.04 97 14.86 98 14.63 99 14.37 100 14.07 101 13.74 102 13.37 103 12.98 104 12.56 105 12.09 106 11.58 107 11.01

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe or depict the antenna from which the plot was made.

Comment: Label your axes, please.

Comment: Please tell us where this information came from - which software generated it, and what the axes mean. I mean I can see that at around 290 centimetres you have about -29 ostriches, but without context it means nothing

Comment: well, we see the typical flightless bird catastrophe happening at 355 centimeters, @ScottEarle. It's clear these ostriches were never linearized before being put through the [Turbo Encabulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ac7G7xOG2Ag). On a more serious note, Derrick, we all assume the x-Axis is degree, but if it was, the plot doesn't make sense at all, so please answer Glenn's answer, and the first thing to do here is fulfill mike's plea for labels :)

Comment: Thank you here is the pattern data https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/10495/how-could-i-understand-the-antenna-pattern-below-from-a-antenna-data. How could I use it in real situation ? I dont know whtere is the begining of 0 degree of H/E pattern.

Comment: the x-Axis is degree.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you might find this article on [Antenna Patterns and their meaning](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/wireless/aironet-antennas-accessories/prod_white_paper0900aecd806a1a3e.html) helpful. In it they provide a diagram showing the typical plot as you would see it drawn; you have already linked to substantially the same image in your question:

[image: Cisco antenna pattern example]

You can see that *in this case*, 0º is the "front" of the antenna, +90º is the left side, -90º/270º is the right side, and ±180º is the back.

I think your question is, "why does my data show a 'main lobe' off to the left side; why is the maximum gain centered around 90º instead of at 0º?"

We cannot answer this question, because you have not told us:

- how the data was obtained
- what the data is supposed to represent

You have shown a chart that looks odd if interpreted as a "final" azimuth plan pattern. But:

- perhaps the data is from a raw collection and has not been centered to the physical antenna?
- perhaps it is an elevation plane pattern instead? (this seems plausible given the lack of symmetry even if re-centered!)
- what others are teasing about: perhaps the data isn't from any antenna measurement at all but something else?

We cannot tell since you have not given us any context of where this data came from and what it is documented to represent.

Note also in that article:

> The orientation of the actual plot is largely dependent on the orientation of the antenna in the measurement system and that's all there is to it.

You can see this at play if you look at their Yagi example diagrams, where the main lobe is recorded at 90º rather than 0º.

Interpreting any plot data depends on [metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata), i.e. some sort of annotation/documentation with details about how it was gathered and its relative reference. Without that it's not much more than random numbers.

---

By the way, here's an example of an elevation pattern from the same article. Because of ground plane effects, the pattern is not so symmetrical:

[image: Cisco elevation diagram example]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! yes!! Now I understand that the 0 degree is the from of the antenna!!! I got the pattern excel data from a datasheet I list some above. Here's the link for the file:https://galtronics.com/extent-d5777i/ .  I am confused about the 90 degree now and the sequences of numbers above especially the highlight meanings.

Comment: Is it possible that because my antenna is directional antenna ???